# Stop CALayer to blur the whole parent view

Tags: cocoa, calayer, nsview, blur, quartz-core

I'm trying to build a blurred, iOS 7 like NSView, which blurs the background.

So far it's working fine by applying a Gaussian background filter to the layer-backed NSView.
The problem is that not only the area right underneath the view gets blurred, but the whole parent view area is blurred.

Layer-backing the parent view doesn't help. Any idea on how to only blur the immediate area of the smaller subview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have to set

`[blurredView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];`.